# i am not able to create a canvas using the below code snippet.The images are not loading too

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //create a array for the loaded Images
  loadedImages = new Array();
  canvas.width = 505;
  canvas.height = 606;
  rowImages = [
    'images/water-block.png', // Top row is water
    'images/stone-block.png', // Row 1 of 3 of stone
    'images/stone-block.png', // Row 2 of 3 of stone
    'images/stone-block.png', // Row 3 of 3 of stone
    'images/grass-block.png', // Row 1 of 2 of grass
    'images/grass-block.png' // Row 2 of 2 of grass
  ];
  numRows = 6;
  numCols = 5;
  //Load images before
  rowImages.forEach(item => {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = item;
    img.onload = function() {
      console.log('Inside the onload Event');
      loadedImages.push(this);
    }
    img.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log('I have an Error with my Images', e);
    }
  });
  for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      ctx.drawImage(img, col * 101, row * 83);
    }
  }
}
```

following are the actions i am trying to perform in the above code snippet:

- creating the canvas.
- creating instance of image.
- initialising array of images.
- painting the images on canvas on load of images.

  i am unable to find what is wrong....when i debug i am neither able to create the canvas nor load the images.....also there are no errors in the console

Comment: on lines 14 to 16 you are using a "," instead of semicolons. Are you sure you not getting any errors?

Comment: I guess that should not cause a problem since it is only declaration of the variables. Nevertheless i tried again by replacing "," with ";" on lines 14 to 16 but the problem still remains.Thanks for the response:)

Comment: Issue is in img.onload function try to debug it

Comment: not getting any error in console for img.onload. The control just skips this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `img.onload` event never fires since there is nothing to load.
You set the `img.src` inside the load event you have to set it outside.

You can load the Images before:

```
//create a array for the loaded Images
var loadedImages = new Array();

//Load images before
rowImages.forEach(item => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = item;
    img.onload = function () {
        console.log('Inside the onload Event');
        loadedImages.push(this);
    }
    img.onerror = function(e){
        console.log('I have an Error with my Images', e);
    }
});
```

After all Images are loaded you can paint them to the Canvas.

Here is now a full example:

```
window.onload = function () {
    /* declaration */
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let loadedImages = new Array();
    let numRows = 6;
    let numCols = 5;
    let rowImages = [
        'images/water-block.png', // Top row is water
        'images/stone-block.png', // Row 1 of 3 of stone
        'images/stone-block.png', // Row 2 of 3 of stone
        'images/stone-block.png', // Row 3 of 3 of stone
        'images/grass-block.png', // Row 1 of 2 of grass
        'images/grass-block.png' // Row 2 of 2 of grass
    ];
    let imageLength = rowImages.length;

    canvas.width = 505;
    canvas.height = 606;        
    rowImages.forEach(item => {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = item;
        img.onload = function(){
            /***********************************************
            **
            **  This event fires, when the Image is loaded.
            **  That does NOT mean, that the first image you started, will be loaded fist as well.
            **  Obviously a 5MB mage takes longer to load, than a 200kb image.
            **  You have to wait until ALL images are loaded.
            **
            ***********************************************/
            loadedImages.push(this);
            if(loadedImages.length === imageLength){
                paintToCanvas(loadedImages,numRows,numCols);
            }
        }
        img.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log('I have an Error with my Images', e);
        }
    });


    /***********************************************
    **
    **  This function is called AFTER all Images are loaded
    **  In here you can do your for loops and paint to Canvas
    **
    ***********************************************/

    function paintToCanvas(loadedImages,numRows,numCols){
        /* Here you can add your for loops and paint to Canvas */
    }
}
```

Comment: the forEach was firstly giving me a referenceError in all the above declared variables. It was resolved when i removed the var from all my declarations. but my previous problem still remains. the control is not entering into the img.onload function.

Comment: The referenceError mostlikely occured because you used the declared the variables inside the `onload`  function, and you used the `forEach` outside of this function. It is hard to say for sure, but it is very likely. 

If your `onload` function still doesn't fire, maybe your path to the images is off. I'll Edit the post and add an Error function as well.

Comment: The control is not at all going into the error function. Moreover, i am not able to understand the flow. it just runs through the forEach loop 6 times without getting into any of the functions inside. then it comes out and runs through the nested for loop 5*6 times. After this the control goes back to the img.onload function and the console.log message is printed for 6 times and the size of loadedImages increases  to 6. I have edited the main code snippet with the updated code.

Comment: I now added a full example with comments. I hope it makes you understand easier. It is not the most beautiful code, but it works for now and hopefully helps you.

Comment: thanks... it is working:) i just need to add "document.body.appendChild(canvas);" to the code snippet

Comment: So maybe you can mark the answer as helpful... would be nice then.

Comment: There's just one last doubt... The required order is one row of water, three rows of stone and two rows of grass[as is the order of images in rowImages]. The order is proper when I run the code... But the order changes whenever I debug the code[it becomes three rows of stone, one row of water and two rows of grass]... I m not able to figure out why since this happens only in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply not adding the canvas to the document.

Might wanna take a look at Promises.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //add the canvas to the document
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  loadedImages = new Array();
  canvas.width = 505;
  canvas.height = 606;
  rowImages = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/10x10',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/20x20',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/30x30',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/40x40',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/50x50',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/60x60'
  ];
  numRows = 6;
  numCols = 5;

  let promises = [];

  rowImages.forEach((item) => {
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = item;
      img.onload = function() {
        loadedImages.push(this);
        res(img);
      }

      img.onerror = function(e) {
        rej('I have an Error with my Images');
      }
    });
    promises.push(promise)
  });

  // after all the promises are resolved
  // means after all the images in the array are loaded
  // do the drawing
  Promise.all(promises).then((img) => {
    for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
      for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
        ctx.drawImage(img[row], col * 101, row * 83);
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Slow networks can cause performance issues